# How to compare two datasets in Splunk and highlight the table cells as per their difference indicator condition?

Tags: splunk

I have different JSON data sets which are indexed to FOOD_DB in Splunk.
In a dashboard I want to compare the any two selected datasets in the dropdown menu.

First dropdown menu is labeled as Current_year 
and the second dropdown is labeled as Comparing_year

I will show the data from the Current_year and highlight the cells based on some conditions.

Sample JSON dataset looks as below :
Lets say for current year

```
{ 
    "Sugar": {
        "prod_rate" : "50",
        "prod_qual" : "Good"
    },
    "Rice": {
        "prod_rate" : "80",
        "prod_qual" : "OK"
    }
}
```

For comparing year

```
{ 
    "Sugar": {
        "prod_rate" : "80",
        "prod_qual" : "Good"
    },
    "Rice": {
        "prod_rate" : "40",
        "prod_qual" : "AVERAGE"
    }
}
```

Condition:

1. if current prod_rate is more than comparing year, cells will be green, if less red.
2. if prod_qual is not equal then yellow

The code I have tried so far is below with coloring of cell using colorPalette. But not able to do the comparison between two data sets selected from separate dropdown and highlight as per the set condition.

```
<form version="1.1" theme="dark">
  <label>COMPARE FOOD DATA/label>
  <description>COMPARISON TABLE</description>
  <fieldset submitButton="false">
    <input type="dropdown" token="curYr">
      <label>Current_year</label>
      <fieldForLabel>cur_year</fieldForLabel>
      <fieldForValue>cur_year</fieldForValue>
      <search>
        <query>
          index=FOOD_DB |stats values(time) as cur_year |mvexpand cur_year
        </query>
 
      </search>
    </input>
  </fieldset>
    <fieldset submitButton="false">
    <input type="dropdown" token="compYr">
      <label>Comparing_year</label>
      <fieldForLabel>comp_year</fieldForLabel>
      <fieldForValue>comp_year</fieldForValue>
      <search>
        <query>
          index=FOOD_DB |stats values(time) as comp_year |mvexpand comp_year
        </query>
 
      </search>
    </input>
  </fieldset>
  <row>
    <panel>
      <title>View and Compare</title>
      <table>
         <option name="count">15</option>
        <search>
          <query> index=FOOD_DB time = $curYr$| eval prod_name = json_array_to_mv(json_keys(_raw))|eval prod_name = mvfilter(NOT match(prod_name, "uploadedBy"))
| mvexpand prod_name
| eval data = json_extract(_raw, prod_name), prod_rate = json_extract(data, "prod_rate"), prod_qual = json_extract(data, "prod_qual")
| table prod_name, prod_rate, prod_qual
| rename prod_name as prod_names
</query>
        </search>
        <format type="color" field="prod_rate">
        <colorPalette type="expression">if(match(value,"80"),"#65A637","#FF0000")</colorPalette>
    </format>
      </table>
    </panel>
  </row>
</form>
```

Comment: Can someone please answer this or give a clue?

Answer (score 2):

I would generate a new field next to the first two (current and last production) labeled, say, "trend"

Populate `trend` with "up" or "down"

Then set conditional formatting on the `trend` field

Here is a toy, run-anywhere Dashboard that does it:

```
<dashboard version="1.1">
  <label>conditional formatting</label>
  <row>
    <panel>
      <table>
        <search>
          <query>| makeresults
| eval break="7;8;up|9;8;down|10;10;even"
| makemv delim="|" break
| mvexpand break
| rex field=break "(?&lt;last&gt;\d+)\D+(?&lt;this&gt;\d+)\W+(?&lt;trend&gt;.+)"
| fields - _time break</query>
          <earliest>-24h@h</earliest>
          <latest>now</latest>
          <sampleRatio>1</sampleRatio>
        </search>
        <option name="count">100</option>
        <option name="dataOverlayMode">none</option>
        <option name="drilldown">none</option>
        <option name="percentagesRow">false</option>
        <option name="rowNumbers">false</option>
        <option name="totalsRow">false</option>
        <option name="wrap">true</option>
        <format type="color" field="trend">
          <colorPalette type="map">{"up":#55C169,"down":#D41F1F}</colorPalette>
        </format>
      </table>
    </panel>
  </row>
</dashboard>
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I have many columns and comparison needs to be done with each then I have to create trend column after each such columns.

Comment: @A.G.Progm.Enthusiast - then extend the logic as needed :)